# Can I exchange owned ships from a different location?

Tags: elite-dangerous

I managed to finally find a station selling the new Imperial Courier... the only problem is that it was nearly 400k LS away from the jump star. I don't really want to spend the 10+ minutes every time I want to switch out ships (especially since it's pretty far from my home star anyway).

Is there anyway to move ships around to a different location? If not, what are my options here?

Comment: Note that in the upcoming update (2.2) - currently in beta testing - one can order a ship which has been stored to be transferred to your current location. Then one should be able to fly to the station, store your old ship and buy a new one, fly back to your home and order the old ship to be transferred. (Posted as a comment because this is not in the official game yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 2.2 Guardians, ships can be transferred (for a fee) between stations.

[2.2 Guardians update release notes](https://forums.frontier.co.uk/showthread.php/300177-Elite-Dangerous-The-Guardians-2-2-update):

> - Option to move owned ships added - it's available from all Shipyards
> - Ability to sell ships remotely (from different ports) added

The functionality is available even without Horizons season pass.

Answer (score 3):

You can store your current ship at system A, and buy a sidewinder. Do not upgrade the sidewinder, and fly it to the Imperial Courier. Buy the courier. You will then be flying the Courier, have your original ship at A, and have a sidewinder you will never use at the 400kLS system.

Comment: I think this answer means "store" in the first sentence, and not "sell"

Comment: There is a maximum to the range a sidewinder can fly without refueling, especially as some of the fuel will be used for jumping to the star.

Comment: @Sjoerd Interesting point, I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to transfer ships. Trust me, I looked.

There are essentially two options you can take:

- Find another place that sells the Imperial Courier (or whatever ship you want), and buy it there.
- Sell your current ship at a 10% loss, and buy the new ship there. Just remember to sell all of your modules and replace the ones you can't sell with the cheapest possible. That way you'll lose a lot less moolah.

Personally, I would go with option 1 if you're currently in anything more expensive than an Asp (Although even a Clipper or Python could make up the loss in a couple hours worth of trading). I wouldn't even *try* for a station 400k Ls from the parent star. I won't touch anything more than 1200 Ls away as a personal rule of thumb, unless it's for a mission I need done.

Comment: My main ship is clipper, but I got the courier because I needed something that can go everywhere (not all outposts have large landing pads)

Comment: Well a Clipper is *only* 2.2 mil loss from the sale assuming you sell all modules first. That's an hour in a decent trade route with the clipper. 35 minutes on my current trade route in my Clipper.

Comment: Option 3, buy a sidewinder from somewhere else, take that to the station with the courier and sell it.